# What is this error that I get after upgrading CometD 2.5.0 to 3.0.6.?

Tags: java, jetty, cometd

I developed a CometD client service in Java, that worked fine until I upgraded CometD 2.5.0 to CometD 3.0.6. (jetty-client-7.6.0 to 9.2.1 as well). 
I had a look at the doc for upgrading, I looked around on Internet and spent time myself. No luck. Hope someone can tell me where I am wrong. 
Here is the exception:

```
2015-11-04 17:18:24 INFO  ResponseNotifier:197 - Exception while notifying listener org.cometd.client.transport.LongPollingTransport$2@35d92de8
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.hash(ConcurrentHashMap.java:333)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:988)
    at org.cometd.common.AbstractClientSession.getReleasableChannel(AbstractClientSession.java:277)
    at org.cometd.common.AbstractClientSession.receive(AbstractClientSession.java:230)
    at org.cometd.client.BayeuxClient.processMessage(BayeuxClient.java:787)
    at org.cometd.client.BayeuxClient$PublishTransportListener.processMessage(BayeuxClient.java:1193)
    at org.cometd.client.BayeuxClient$PublishTransportListener.onMessages(BayeuxClient.java:1185)
    at org.cometd.client.transport.LongPollingTransport$2.onComplete(LongPollingTransport.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.ResponseNotifier.notifyComplete(ResponseNotifier.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.ResponseNotifier.notifyComplete(ResponseNotifier.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpReceiver.terminateResponse(HttpReceiver.java:446)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpReceiver.responseSuccess(HttpReceiver.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.messageComplete(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseContent(HttpParser.java:1430)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:1272)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.parse(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.process(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.receive(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpChannelOverHTTP.receive(HttpChannelOverHTTP.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpConnectionOverHTTP.onFillable(HttpConnectionOverHTTP.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Please find my Java client code:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.start();
final String cometdUrl = RestAssured.baseURI + COMETD_PATH;
ClientTransport transport = new LongPollingTransport(null, httpClient);
bayeuxClient = new BayeuxClient(cometdUrl, transport);
bayeuxClient.putCookie(new HttpCookie("JSESSIONID", token));
bayeuxClient.getChannel(Channel.META_HANDSHAKE).addListener(new ClientSessionChannel.MessageListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(ClientSessionChannel channel, Message message) {
        if (message.isSuccessful()) {
            logger.info("Handshake done!");
            for (UVChannel channelValue : UV_CHANNELS) {
                bayeuxClient.getChannel(channelValue.value()).subscribe(new ClientSessionChannel.MessageListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMessage(ClientSessionChannel channel, Message message) {
                        if (message.isSuccessful()) { 
                            try {
                                BlockingQueue<Message> notificationsPerChannel = notifications.get(uvChannel(message.getChannel()));
                                notificationsPerChannel.put(message);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                throw new IllegalStateException("It was not possible to store a message in the queue");
                            }
                        } else throw new IllegalStateException("no subscription to channel: " + message);
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Handshake failed! " + cometdUrl);
        }
    }
});
bayeuxClient.handshake();
```

Comment: The error is quite particular, since it happens in case a subscription has been denied by the server _and_ the reply message that comes back does not have the `subscription` field. Can you [enable DEBUG logging](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/#_troubleshooting) on the client and server and update the question with those logs ?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't attach my log file because is too messy with other stuff... Anyway I created a JavaScript client version as well and it works fine, please find attached the Java client that may be the problem.

Comment: The problem is on the server application. Do you expect that the subscription is rejected by the server ? If you don't, then it's a misconfiguration of the server application. The CometD DEBUG logs of the server would tell. Your client code looks fine, although I would not use a BlockingQueue (CometD is asynchronous and you don't want to block it inside a callback, possibly forever).

Comment: I just tried to use a previous version of CometD 2.5.0 (Jetty 7.6.0) on the Java client side. It worked like a charm, without changing a single line on the server side. Something is missing from the whole picture.

Comment: All right, so do you have a reproducible test case that does not involve `UV_CHANNELS`, that only uses the CometD APIs and has no dependencies ? If you do, please file an issue at https://github.com/cometd/cometd/issues. Thanks !

Comment: I also get this issue regularly. Is this fixed in a later jetty/cometd version ? Or is there a way I can avoid the exception if no harm ?